marginfi::accounts and marginfi::instruction
I came across a code that didn't find an explanation in the official documentation.
the project github :https://github.com/mrgnlabs/marginfi-v2.git
I have a line of code in the make_bank_borrow_ix function in the file test-utils/src/marginfi_account.rs that is marginfi::instruction::LendingAccountBorrow, and when I use the code to jump to it, it jumps to a function with the same name, which is obviously not what I want, but I can't find where this structure is defined, can you guys help me?
let mut ix = Instruction {
            program_id: marginfi::id(),
            accounts,
            data: marginfi::instruction::LendingAccountBorrow {
                amount: ui_to_native!(ui_amount.into(), bank.mint.mint.decimals),
            }
            .data(),
        };

when click the code jump:
pub fn lending_account_borrow<'info>(
        ctx: Context<'_, '_, 'info, 'info, LendingAccountBorrow<'info>>,
        amount: u64,
    ) -> MarginfiResult {
        marginfi_account::lending_account_borrow(ctx, amount)
    }

That is confused for me. That should be a struct. I think has some rule to generate the function to struct? may be.

https://github.com/mrgnlabs/marginfi-v2/blob/7b10c51b9934130b029f220c410e517c0ad8c7c4/programs/marginfi/src/instructions/marginfi_account/borrow.rs#L24 appears to be the function you're looking for

I know it's this function, but my question is, why does the off chain client program call the function of the smart contract written on the anchor in the form of a structure.
